# Unable to send a POST request. Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Tags: post, angular7

So, I have gone through most of the similar questions on GitHub and StackOverflow.

In `my issue.component.ts` file, I have bound the value of a dropdown menu to a variable `issueInformation`. Now, I need to send this data to the server and I'm using post request for that.

This is my `issue.component.ts` file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';
import { IssuesService } from '../issues.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-issue',
  templateUrl: './issue.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./issue.component.css']
})
export class IssueComponent implements OnInit,  DoCheck {

issueInfo: any[] = [];
issueInformation: any;
    httpClient: any;
    http: any;
  constructor(private issue: IssuesService) { }
ngDoCheck(): void {
        console.log('issue:', this.issueInformation);
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getIssues();
  }
    getIssues() {

        console.log('issue::', this.issueInformation);

        this.issue.allIssues().
    subscribe(
      data2 => {
          this.issueInfo = data2.Issues;

      },
      err => console.log(err),
      () => console.log('complete')
    );

  }


}
```

Since, I'm new to Angular I tried one of the examples with POST request and added it to this file after the `getIssues()` function:

```
doPOST() {
  console.log("POST");
  let url = `${this.apiRoot}/post`;
  this.http.post(url, {moo:"foo",goo:"loo"}).subscribe(res => console.log(res.json()));
}
```

I also tried adding `(change)="doPOST($event.target.value)"` to my dropdown select line in HTML.

The error I'm getting is:

```
AppComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
    at IssueComponent.getIssues (issue.component.ts:30)
    at IssueComponent.ngOnInit (issue.component.ts:24)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:24489)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:35151)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:35090)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:36112)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:36055)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:7)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:36043)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35055)
```

I tried the following: 
`constructor{private issue: IssuesService,private http: Http}` 
But it doesn't work for me.

I also tried to shift the doPOST() function in `issues.service.ts` file but I'm not able to call it in `issue.component.ts` file.

Here is the `issues.service.ts` file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { IssueComponent } from './issue/issue.component';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})


export class IssuesService {

  url = 'http://localhost:8080/issueTypes';
_baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  allIssues(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
 doPost() {
      console.log('POST');
      const url = '/api/issue';
      this.http.post(url, {moo: 'foo', goo: 'loo'}).subscribe(res => console.log(res.json()));
                                          }
}
```

Can someone please tell me what's going wrong? If what I'm doing is wrong from the start, then please tell me how I can send back the value of `issueInformation` to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending the entire day trying to figure this out, I found the solution:

`constructor(private issue: IssuesService, private httpClient: HttpClient) { }`

And after adding this, the POST request can be put in the same file as `issue.component.ts` as follows:

```
postIssue() {
      this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:8080/uploadFile', 
      {issueInformation: this.issueInformation}).subscribe((data: any) => 
      console.log(data));
  }
```